# Let X be a space and C a connected subset of X. Suppose $C \subset D\subset\bar C$. Then D is connected.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

This is how i showed it works.

Let X be a space and C a connected subset of X. Suppose, C $\subset$ D $\subset$ $\overline{C}$, Then D is connected.\
Let, C $\subset$ X be connected and suppose C $\subset$ D $\subset$ $\overline{C}$. Then, if U,V $\not=$ $\emptyset$ form a separation of D, then we have U $\cap$ $\overline{V}$ = $\overline{U}$ $\cap$ V = $\emptyset$, because U is closed in D and the closure of U in D is given by $\overline{U}$ $\cap$ D. So,  U = $\overline{U}$ $\cap$ D. So, $\emptyset$ = U $\cap$ V = ($\overline{U}$ $\cap$ D)$\cap$ V = $\overline{U}$ $\cap$ V. By symmetry, we can get the other part: $\overline{V}$ $\cap$ U = $\emptyset$.\
Furthermore, either C $\subset$ U or C $\subset$ V (from proposition 3.79). So if not, then we have U $\cap$ C $\not=$ $\emptyset$ and V $\cap$ C $\not=$ $\emptyset$ open in C and disjoint. Therefore, they form a separation of C, which is impossible.\
So, WLOG, lets assume C $\subset$ U. Then, $\overline{C}$ $\subset$ $\overline{U}$. Since, V $\cap$ $\overline{U}$ = $\emptyset$. Therefore, we have that $\overline{C}$ $\cap$ V = $\emptyset$, and for V $\subset$ D, we will have V = D $\cap$ V = $\emptyset$, its a contradiction.\
Therefore, D is connected. (Proved)

Hope this looks good. Can someone verify this? If there is anything wrong or somewhere it needs better notation pls let me know. Appreciate your help!!

Comment: The problem has been asked here before.... You correctly obtained $\bar C \cap V=\phi,$  (2nd-last line), after which you should say $\therefore V=D\cap V\subset \bar C\cap V=\phi,$ so $V=\phi.$ As a matter of good writing, in the 1st line, after "... then $D$ is connected. " , you should write "Proof:"... & don't use \ as a separator. Start a new paragraph instead.

Comment: ok, gotcha. '\' is used for latex. I directly copy pasted it from there to math stack exchange hence this happened. Sorry for that. Appreciate your comments. Will change those. Is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: Your reference to Prop 3.79 is ok if this is directed to someone who has & knows the textbook.... BTW,  a useful corollary, when $D=\bar C=X,$ is that if $X$ has a dense connected subspace $C$ then $X$ is connected.

Comment: yah, thats a proposition which I proved in class. haha :P :D So I'm good. Yeah the corollary is useful and is used a lot when it comes to connected and dense connected spaces.